# Can polarized light wave rotate propagating through space?

Tags: photons, polarization, rotation

We all experienced phenomenon of polarized light as well as optical filters that make such polarization detectable.
However, if object emitting that light was rotating around the axis of emission, does that mean that polarization itself will be rotating with the same speed as such polarized light propagates through space?

Comment: You have answered your own question and your intuition is correct. It has to do with the momentum that the particles give to the photon.

Answer (score 1):

If the light is linearly polarised then it will keep that polarisation during propagation. Orientation of the polarisation being dependent on the orientation of the object emitting the polarised light. However, consider two common-mode em waves which have orthogonal linear polarisations, if these waves are out of phase by one quarter of their wavelength, then the resulting polarisation vector will rotate. This is called [circularly polarised light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization).